# Checking if element is in hash?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

Ok, I have the following hash and am trying to match the referenced element:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '743' => '00:1',
          '20687' => '01:3',
};
```

Could someone tell me how do I check to see if the value '00:1' (as an example) matches another variable? This is what I currently have and is not working:

```
if($pids{$pid} == qr/$time/){
    $pids{$pid}{$time}[$y] = $line;
    $y++;
};
```

I've also tried `if(exists($pids{$pid}{$time}))` and a few others.

**UPDATE**

Pertaining to the questions below, pids is a hash, %pids.

This is how the hash table comes out when I run it without matching to $time which is exactly what I want:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '743' => '00:1',
          '4771' => {
                      '23:5' => [
                                  'Dec  1 23:59:23 ftp1 ftpd[4771]: USER test
',
                                  'Dec  1 23:59:23 ftp1 ftpd[4771]: PASS password
',
                                  'Dec  1 23:59:23 ftp1 ftpd[4771]: FTP LOGIN FROM 192.168.0.2 [192.168.0.2], test
',
                                  'Dec  1 23:59:23 ftp1 ftpd[4771]: CWD /home/test/
',
                                  'Dec  1 23:59:23 ftp1 ftpd[4771]: TYPE Image
',
                                  'Dec  1 23:59:23 ftp1 ftpd[4771]: PASV
',
                                  'Dec  1 23:59:23 ftp1 ftpd[4771]: RETR test
',
                                  'Dec  1 23:59:23 ftp1 ftpd[4771]: QUIT
',
                                  'Dec  1 23:59:23 ftp1 ftpd[4771]: FTP session closed
'
                                ]
                    },
```

Here's an example of the data that would come through:

```
Dec  1 23:59:03 ftp1 ftpd[4771]: USER test
Dec  1 23:59:03 ftp1 ftpd[4771]: PASS password  
Dec  1 23:59:03 ftp1 ftpd[4771]: FTP LOGIN FROM 192.168.0.02 [192.168.0.2], test  
Dec  1 15:02:03 ftp1 ftpd[4771]: CWD /home/test  # Looks same but different time so not a match  
Dec  1 23:59:03 ftp1 ftpd[4771]: CWD /home/test  
Dec  1 23:59:03 ftp1 ftpd[4771]: TYPE Image
```

So as you can see above, I could have two lines with different "pids", I only want to match the one of those times, not both.

If you need more info on this, I have all the details in another question I have open but seems to be dead in the water: *[Playing with Hashes from a FTP flow in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23067611/playing-with-hashes-from-a-ftp-flow-in-perl)*

Comment: `$pids` is an array ref?

Comment: Could you maybe provide a bit more background? Could you perhaps show what your input is, and what data structure or result you want to create? I think you want to append each line to the appropriate hash entry, but your question doesn't currently make that clear.

Comment: I'm not sure how you can compare `$pids{$pid}` but then later treat it as an array ref

Comment: I have updated my question with the answers to your questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can extract the `$time` from each line, this is easy:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dump;

my %pids;

while (my $line = <>) {
    chomp $line;
    my ($time, $pid) = $line =~ /([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]) .*? \[([0-9]+)\] /x or next;
    push @{ $pids{$pid}{$time} }, $line;
}

dd \%pids;

__DATA__
Dec  1 23:59:03 ftp1 ftpd[4771]: USER test
Dec  1 23:59:03 ftp1 ftpd[4771]: PASS password  
Dec  1 23:59:03 ftp1 ftpd[4771]: FTP LOGIN FROM 192.168.0.02 [192.168.0.2], test  
Dec  1 15:02:03 ftp1 ftpd[4771]: CWD /home/test  # Looks same but different time so not a match  
Dec  1 23:59:03 ftp1 ftpd[4771]: CWD /home/test  
Dec  1 23:59:03 ftp1 ftpd[4771]: TYPE Image
Dec  2 23:12:03 ftp1 ftpd[1234]: USER test
Dec  2 23:12:03 ftp1 ftpd[1234]: PASS password  
Dec  2 23:12:03 ftp1 ftpd[1234]: CWD /home/test
```

which would produce the following output:

```
{
  1234 => {
            "23:1" => [
              "Dec  2 23:12:03 ftp1 ftpd[1234]: USER test",
              "Dec  2 23:12:03 ftp1 ftpd[1234]: PASS password  ",
              "Dec  2 23:12:03 ftp1 ftpd[1234]: CWD /home/test ",
            ],
          },
  4771 => {
            "15:0" => [
                        "Dec  1 15:02:03 ftp1 ftpd[4771]: CWD /home/test  # Looks same but different time so not a match  ",
                      ],
            "23:5" => [
                        "Dec  1 23:59:03 ftp1 ftpd[4771]: USER test",
                        "Dec  1 23:59:03 ftp1 ftpd[4771]: PASS password  ",
                        "Dec  1 23:59:03 ftp1 ftpd[4771]: FTP LOGIN FROM 192.168.0.02 [192.168.0.2], test  ",
                        "Dec  1 23:59:03 ftp1 ftpd[4771]: CWD /home/test  ",
                        "Dec  1 23:59:03 ftp1 ftpd[4771]: TYPE Image",
                      ],
          },
}
```

If you are only interested in a predefined set of PIDs and times, you could perhaps do something like:

```
my %pids = (
    5678 => { '00:1' => [] },
    4771 => { '23:5' => [] },
);

while (my $line = <>) {
    chomp $line;
    my ($time, $pid) = $line =~ /([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]) .*? \[([0-9]+)\] /x or next;
    if (exists $pids{$pid} and exists $pids{$pids}{$time}) {
        push @{ $pids{$pid}{$time} }, $line;
    }
}
```

or

```
my %times;
@times{qw/ 00:01 23:5 /} = ();

...

    push @{ $pids{$pid}{$time} }, $line if exists $times{$time};
```

If there is no way to extract the time from the line in a general manner, you could match all possible times:

```
my %pids = (
    5678 => { '00:1' => [] },
    4771 => { '23:5' => [] },
);

while (my $line = <>) {
    chomp $line;
    my ($pid) = $line =~ /\[([0-9]+)\]/ or next;
    next if not exists $pids{$pid};
    my $time_regex = join '|', map quotemeta, keys %{ $pids{$pid} };
    my ($time) = $line =~ /($time_regex)/ or next;
    push @{ $pids{$pid}{$time} }, $line;
}
```

Comment: I was thinking your last example might work but it gives me "Can't use string ("05:3") as a HASH ref while "strict refs"" at the `my $time_regex` line

Comment: @cycloxr Notice that I directly initialize my `%pids` as a hash of hashes of arrays, whereas you have a hash of strings. You could convert your hash via `$_ = { $_ => [] } for values %pids` before the loop or use my schema directly.

Comment: I assume the following is not the way to do that? `foreach my $key(keys %pids){
 $_ = map { $_ => [] } ${pids}{$key}=>[];
}`

Comment: I also tried `foreach my $key(keys %pids){
 $_ = map { $_ => [] } %pids}=>[];
}`

Comment: @cycloxr Unfortunately, those two snippets you've shown don't work. E.g. `map` in scalar context returns the number of elements, your second snippet has a `}` too much, and `$_` will not refer to the current value if you loop over the keys with an explicit loop variable. The snippet in my previous comment would work, and it is equivalent to `for my $key (keys %pids) { $pids{$key} = { $pids{$key} => [] }; }`.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! that did the job! I appreciate your help! Steeper learning curve than I remember when I was younger ;)